# Transform error while launching multiple turtlebots in ROS NOETIC

Tags: ros, rviz, tf2-ros

I am trying to launch 3 turtlebots following this  : [repo](https://github.com/airuchen/multi_turtlebot3/tree/multibots-dev) in **ros noetic.**
this is my gazebo launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3"  default="tb3_0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3" default="tb3_1"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3" default="tb3_2"/>

  <arg name="first_tb3_x_pos" default="11.466219"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_y_pos" default="-7.267796"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_z_pos" default="-0.000"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_yaw"   default="1.621071"/>

  <arg name="second_tb3_x_pos" default="8.143804"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_y_pos" default="0.032318"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_z_pos" default="-0.001064"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_yaw"   default="-0.309337"/>

  <arg name="third_tb3_x_pos" default="18.376935"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_y_pos" default="-1.841782"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_z_pos" default="-0.000988"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_yaw"   default="2.441699"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <!-- <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/tb3_worlds/turtlebot3_world.world"/> -->
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/scene2.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>  

  <group ns = "$(arg first_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher0" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg first_tb3)" />
    </node>
    
    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg first_tb3) -x $(arg first_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg first_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg first_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg first_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

  <group ns = "$(arg second_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher1" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg second_tb3)" />
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg second_tb3) -x $(arg second_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg second_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg second_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg second_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

  <group ns = "$(arg third_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher2" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg third_tb3)" />
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg third_tb3) -x $(arg third_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg third_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg third_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg third_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

</launch>
```

The tf tree of eahc robot is sepearte and the map fram eis missing on rviz which is showing global status error and nop transform error.

[rviz error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oGFG.png)...

below is the tf tree:

[tf tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDYMW.png)

I tried multiple ways o flaunching the navigation stack but the tf tree remains seperate for each robot and there is no map frame.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 separate transformation trees and `odom` subtree referring to `/base_footprint`:

[image: Part of the tree]

It would help if you separated the odometry generator for every robot in Gazebo to make odometry available for every robot.